# Assign values to a variable, conditional on a factor variable

Tags: r, conditional-statements, vectorization

I want to create a variable that takes values from a numeric vector, conditional on a factor variable.

I have a numeric vector

```
x <- c(0, 1000, 50000)
```

And a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1:8), z = c("A", "A", "C", NA, "B", "A", NA, NA))
```

> ```
>    ID    z
>  1  1    A
>  2  2    A
>  3  3    C
>  4  4 <NA>
>  5  5    B
>  6  6    A
>  7  7 <NA>
>  8  8 <NA>
> ```

I want to create a variable `y` taking the value `x[1]` if `z=="A"`, `x[2]` if `z=="B"`, and `x[3]` if `z=="C"`.

My desired output

> ```
>    ID    z   y
> 1   1    A   0
> 2   2    A   0
> 3   3    C   50000
> 4   4    NA  NA
> 5   5    B   1000
> 6   6    A   0
> 7   7    NA  NA
> 8   8    NA  NA
> ```

I tried with

```
df$y[which(df$z == "A")] <- x[1]
df$y[which(df$z == "B")] <- x[2]
df$y[which(df$z == "C")] <- x[3]
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the desired result

Comment: @simone Are these of the same lengths ie. `z` and `x`

Comment: @akrun no, length(z)>length(x)

Comment: @simone I posted one way. Hope it helps.

Comment: @simone what about the other values in `z`?  Do they remain as such?

Comment: @akrun not quite. thanks though. I don't understand the last question

Comment: @simone I meant whether you want NA to be filled in the `y` column for `z` values `D`, `E`, etc.

Comment: @akrun Edited, hope it's more clear

Comment: @simone So, now you don't have `D`, `E`, etc..

Comment: letters are from A to K and there are NA's. I just thought it was better to keep it simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you describe and insert `NA` into the `y` column if `z` is not `A`, `B`, or `C`.

```
set.seed(84)
df <- data.frame(z = sample(LETTERS[1:11], 15, replace = TRUE))
x <- c(0,1000,50000)

df$y <- ifelse(df$z == "A", x[1], ifelse(df$z == "B", x[2], ifelse(df$z == "C", x[3], NA)))

df
#    z     y
# 1  I    NA
# 2  D    NA
# 3  J    NA
# 4  I    NA
# 5  C 50000
# 6  C 50000
# 7  B  1000
# 8  D    NA
# 9  G    NA
# 10 B  1000
# 11 I    NA
# 12 K    NA
# 13 J    NA
# 14 K    NA
# 15 A     0
```

It's unclear from your post what should happen if `z` is not `A`, `B`, `C`; if your real needs are more complicated, the nested `ifelse()` statements will get pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
  df$y <- x[as.numeric(df$z)]
```

if the `column` `z` is not `factor`

```
  df$y <- x[as.numeric(factor(df$z))]    
  head(df)
  #  ID z     y
  #1  1 C 50000
  #2  2 B  1000
  #3  3 H    NA
  #4  4 F    NA
  #5  5 G    NA
  #6  6 K    NA
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(ID=1:40, z=sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:11]), 40, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: The poster said that `z` goes from `A` to `K` though.

Comment: @Kara Woo Thanks for the comment.  It's not clear whether other values are NA or not.

Comment: yes, there are missing values in z, sorry I did not specify that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `match`.  This fills the non-matched values with `NA`

```
df$y <- x[match(df$z, c("A", "B", "C"))]
df
#   ID z     y
# 1  1 A     0
# 2  2 A     0
# 3  3 C 50000
# 4  4 D    NA
# 5  5 B  1000
# 6  6 A     0
# 7  7 H    NA
# 8  8 E    NA
```

Note that OP has changed the data since I posted my original answer.  It still works.